# Running the Hello World C code from command prompt?

Tags: c, windows, dos

I have written a very simple C program to print "Hello World" in my Notepad text editor and saved it as test1.exe. I opened my cmd and ran the file test.exe and the received error is as follows:

> The NTVDM CPU has encountered an Illegeal instruction.  CS:0607
>   IP:0103 OP:63 6c 75 64 65 Choose 'Close' to terminate the application.

Comment: You need to compile the code, you can't just save it as an `exe`.

Comment: I don't have an IDE in my window's system so can I compile it without any IDE?

Comment: @sarkar.shukla - You don't need an IDE. You need a compiler. Get one, like maybe [this](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/HOWTO).

Comment: Or just run the code on a site such as http://codepad.org or http://ideone.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things to help you learn C in an easier manner:

- First, you say you wrote it in Notepad. Bad choice for learning C. Notepad does not support Syntax highlighting.
- Second, C needs to be compiled, on windows you have a few choice for compiler, the first would be MinGW which is Free.
- Third, and IDE that is MinGW aware and C syntax aware is also needed. Geany is simple enough but is very smart and full of sweets.

Finally, see the tutorial here, how to get them all working: [geany+mingw on windows](http://grandfiles.com/tutorials/mingw/index.html).

One more thing, totally unrelated to C, or maybe it does. 
I bluntly assume that C is your first programming experience, or that you are still doing first steps in programming.
C as a first language is VERY BAD. It is not forgiving, and most compilers pass things, but the code will crash, not letting you know what you did wrong.
Consider learing other languages first, a few good choices would be:

1. Python
2. Lua
3. Ruby

Comment: @tomfanning, Java is fine if you *must*, but I would keep my fingers away from it. Deploying big java apps is complicated. Plus Java shoves Objects down your throat, so it's bad as first programming language. C#, well, if you want to frickle with windows forever, go ahead. If you aim for a cool job or a startup, than C# is a bad choice.

Answer (score 4):

You need to save the file as `test.c` and then *compile* it to `test.exe`. The exact details of how you compile it will depend on what C compiler you have installed, but for [cygwin](http://cygwin.com) or [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org) it would be:

```
$ gcc -Wall test.c -o test.exe
```

If you don't have a compiler installed yet and just want to quickly try running a small C program then a further alternative is to use a site such as [codepad.org](http://codepad.org) or [ideone.com](http://ideone.com) where you can type (or paste) your code and run it online.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a compiler and environment for C, I'd go with [Visual Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/express) instead of the other suggestions. It's much more comfortable and offers a fuller Windowsy feel. And it's also free.